# How to get a link to the MDScreen that is created when a button is pressed?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I want to make a dictionary. Dictionary data is stored in a JSON file. To avoid creating a lot of screens, I want to create a screen when an item in the list with the name of the text of this item is pressed, and by this name I can access the JSON file. The problem is that when initializing the list of educational modules, I cannot get the name of the screen on which this list should be located because it has not been created yet.

```
class FolderList(MDList):
        def __init__(self, folders=[], **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.folders = get_list_value('folders.json')
            for folder in list(self.folders):
                item = ItemDrawer(icon='folder', text=folder, screen_name = folder)
                item.bind(on_release= self.to_eximine)
                self.add_widget(item)
        def to_eximine(self, instance):
            sm = self.parent.parent.parent.parent
            try:
                eximine_screen = sm.get_screen(instance.screen_name)
            except:
                eximine_screen = Eximine(name=instance.screen_name)
                sm.add_widget(eximine_screen)
            sm.current = instance.screen_name

class Eximine(MDScreen):
        def __init__(self,  **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
    class EximineList(MDList):
        def __init__(self, modules=[], **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            #self.name = self.parent.parent.parent.parent
    
            self.modules = get_list_value('folders.json')
    
            for module in self.modules:
    
                item = ItemDrawer(icon="school", text=module, screen_name=module)
                item.bind(on_release= self.v_parent )
                self.add_widget(item)
        def v_parent(self,instance):
            print(self.parent.parent.parent.parent)
```

File .kv

```
    <Eximine>:
        id: eximine_list
        ScreenManager:
    
    
            MDScreen:
    
                MDBoxLayout:
                    size_hint_x: 0.5
                    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,}
                    ScrollView:
    
                        EximineList:
                            id: eximine
                            spacing: root.height / 10
```

How to initialize the `EximineList` class during its creation?

I tried to save to a .txt file and use `app = MDApp.get_running_app()`, but the result is the same - the screen has not been created yet.